# RecyclerView within AlertDialog, how to dismiss dialog onClick of RecyclerViewAdapter button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

[Image of RecyclerView within AlertDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Rm1.png)

I have a RecyclerView within my AlertDialog as seen on the image.
My problem is if I click a button (The Check Button, this button is instantiated in the RecyclerViewAdapter) within that RecyclerView, how do I dismiss the dialog which is in another View?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the instance of dialog to recycler view adapter and then dismiss the dialog in recycler view adapter on click of button.